# Modal closing when pop up is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog

I'm making a simple jQuery pop up modal. I know I should just use a plugin but I want to at least understand the mechanics of how it works before using a plugin so im creating my own.

here is the html:

```
<div id="box">
<div id="modal">
<a href="#" class="close"><div>close</div></a>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 style="text-align:center">Title Here</h1>
        <p style="text-align:center">Do what ever you want here crete a form add an image gallery etc.</p>
    </div>

</div>
</div>



<div id="wrapper">
    <h1>This is a Very Simple/Lightweight jQuery Modal Pop Up!</h1>
    <a href="#" class="reveal">Click Me!</a>
</div><!-- END WRAPPER -->
```

the css:

```
#modal{
background-color: #fff;
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
z-index: 50;
position:absolute;
border-radius: 8px;
}
```

and now the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// hide the modal on page load
$('#box').hide();

//show modal when the link is clicked
$('.reveal').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    pageWidth  = $(window).width();
    pageHeight = $(document).height();
    modalLeft = Math.max(pageWidth - $('#modal').outerWidth(),  0) / 2;
    modalTop  = Math.max($(window).height() - $('#modal').outerHeight(),  0) /   2;

    $('#box').fadeIn("slow").css({
        "background-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)",
        "width"           : pageWidth,
        "height"          : pageHeight,
        "z-index"         : "10",
        'position'        :'absolute',
        'top'             :'0',
        'left'            :'0'
    });
    $('#modal').fadeIn("slow").css({
        'top'             : modalTop + $(window).scrollTop(), 
        'left'            : modalLeft + $(window).scrollLeft()
    });
});

// close modal
$('.close').click(function(){
    $('#box').fadeOut("slow");
});
$('#box').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut("slow");
});


});
```

here is a jsfiddle so it can be seen in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/dNj4b/

The problem that I am having is that I want the pop up to close only when the overlay is clicked;howver, it closes even when just the pop up box is clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in the jsFiddle you posted you have this:

```
$('#box').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Remove it.

The thing is, your wrapper/outer div that is being used as overlay is `#box`

```
 $('#box').fadeIn("slow").css({
        "background-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)",
        "width"           : pageWidth,
        "height"          : pageHeight,
        "z-index"         : "10",
        'position'        :'absolute',
        'top'             :'0',
        'left'            :'0'
    });
```

and you have a click event handler attached to it firing a `fadeout`.

**EDIT:**

To be able to close it just with the overlay use this:

```
    $('#box').click(function(e){
        if (e.target.id != 'box'){return false;}
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");
    });
```

### [**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9sjVQ/)

Comment: yes but i want the pop up to close when the overlay is clicked

Comment: You really have to stop beating me to the answers ;)

Comment: this doesn't close the pop up when the overlay is clicked

Comment: @Jack, you will gain up speed soon also :)

Comment: @Sergio I answered since your's wasn't 100% finished tho ;)

Comment: thank you thats exacly the solution i was looking for

Answer (score 3):

You need to move your overlay from being the wrapper for the modal to just a placeholder tag. It should not be parent of the modal. Click event on the modal will propagate to the click event of the overlay and it evetually closes. Try this way:

Move `box` out

```
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="modal">    <a href="#" class="close"><div>close</div></a>

    <div class="wrapper">
            <h1 style="text-align:center">Title Here</h1>

        <p style="text-align:center">Do what ever you want here crete a form add an image gallery etc.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bbxNT/)**

and add these:

```
   $('#box, #modal').hide();

    // close modal
    $('.close').click(function () {
        $('#box, #modal').fadeOut("slow");
    });
    $('#box').click(function () {
        $(this).add('#modal').fadeOut("slow");
    });
```

Comment: thanks thats i thought the solution was i was just trying to see if there was a better solution

Comment: @swsa that is the way all plugin's i know of does, like twitter boostrap, simplemodal etc... because overlay is an absolutely positioned div with some height and width  it doesn't need to wrap up the actual modal at all.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/dNj4b/17/

Change HTML to:

```
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="modal">
    <a href="#" class="close"><div>close</div></a>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 style="text-align:center">Title Here</h1>
        <p style="text-align:center">Do what ever you want here crete a form add an image gallery etc.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add this to css:

```
#modal{
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 50;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display:none;****
}
```

Add this to jquery:

```
// close modal
    $('.close').click(function(){
        $('#box').fadeOut("slow");
        ***$('#modal').fadeOut("slow");
    });
    $('#box').click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");
        ***$('#modal').fadeOut("slow");
    });
```